# Erlang MongoDB Bson Undefined function Mongo

Tags: mongodb, erlang, undefined, bson

I have a problem with mongodb driver.

When I install mongodb-master and try the tutorial from official README file, in the line `> {ok, Conn} = mongo:connect(Host).` the shell gave me the following error: "undefined function mongo:connect/1".

In the README file specifically is indicated that the mongodb driver depends on another erlang lib "bson". The essence of the problem is here. Many times I tried mongo:connect, but the response was the same.
Then I read and installed this: https://github.com/TonyGen/mongodb-erlang/

Now it works.

I hope this will be helpfull for mates with the same problem.

Comment: If you already have a solution, don't place it in question -- answer below.